# Android - CustomAdapter<MyClass> do not get object

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, adapter

I create an custom adapter to send my itens to My adapter class.

My item:

```
  public ItemAcompanhe(String dataPar, String cabecalhoPar, String descricaoPar, int imagePar){
    this.data = dataPar;
    this.cabecalho = cabecalhoPar;
    this.descricao = descricaoPar;
    this.image = imagePar;
}
```

MyAdapter

```
 public AdapterAcompanheSantana(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ItemAcompanhe> objects/*, String[] objects2*/) {
    //super(context, resource, objects);
    super(context, resource, objects);
}
```

My adapter where I set itens:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_acompanhe,null);

    ItemAcompanhe holder = null;
    holder = new ItemAcompanhe(jsonItemAcompanhe);

    // ImageView     item_acompanhe_btn_topo
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_acompanhe_btn_topo);
    img.setBackgroundResource(image[position]);

    // TextView      item_acompanhe_txt_cabecalho   CABECALHO DESCRICAO
    TextView textViewTituloAgendaFragItem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_acompanhe_txt_cabecalho);
    textViewTituloAgendaFragItem.setText(listaDeCabecalhos[position]);

    // TextView      item_acompanhe_txt_data
    TextView textViewDatasAgendaFragItem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_acompanhe_txt_data);
    textViewDatasAgendaFragItem.setText(listaDeDatas[position]);

    // TextView      item_acompanhe_txt_conteudo
    TextView textViewDescricaoAgendaFragItem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_acompanhe_txt_conteudo);
    textViewDescricaoAgendaFragItem.setText(listaDeDescricao[position]);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    textViewDescricaoAgendaFragItem.setTypeface(font);



    return v;
}
```

I cannot get ANY item from my list set as parameter on in Adapter.
Anyone know how I resolve that?

Comment: how you are retrieving values ?? I mean I didn't see you are using position variable any where ?

Answer (score 1):

this

```
ItemAcompanhe holder = null;
holder = new ItemAcompanhe(jsonItemAcompanhe);
```

should be replaced with

```
ItemAcompanhe holder = getItem(position);
```

that will fetch an item from the dataset (handled in your case by the superclass). I would recomend you to avoid to inflate a new convertView every time getView is called, but only when `convertView` is null

```
 if (convertView == null) {     
    convertView = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_acompanhe,null);
 }
```

and return `convertView`

Answer (score 0):

I solve that using:

```
 Myclass extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
```

Adapter creator

```
public AdapterAcompanheSantana(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ItemAcompanhe> objects/*, String[] objects2*/) {
    //super(context, resource, objects);
    super(context, 0, objects);
}
```

GetView:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_acompanhe,null);

    Item atual = getItem(position);
```